# Is it acceptable to split one wide wire into two narrower wires in PCB layout?

Tags: pcb, layout

I have an issue about connecting power wire to the IC. The power wire (50mil) is wide than the pin width of destination IC, so I want to split the wide wire into two narrower ones(20mil) which match the pin width. May it cause a negative effect on signal integrity? Or is there any common solution in this scenario?

[image]

Comment: We don't normally worry about signal integrity on a net labeled "VCC3.6_BAT". Power integrity is more about how close can you put a bypass capacitor to those pins.

Comment: Basic idea is fine. Close to the pin, narrow the traces to same width as pin or slightly narrower. Add a small fill (rectangle) near the pins and route all three traces into the fill.

Answer (score 2):

This has no effect on signal integrity. However, it will have an effect when soldering the chip.

You have to make sure there is no copper between the pads, as this will bridge when soldering. This will look like a short for anyone optically checking the board.
You can usually do this with copper planes, or with traces. See what works.

Try at least to get this:
[image]